# Translate cipher process from java to nodejs (Blowfish)

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, blowfish

We're migrating an old middleware written in java to our server and we want to write it down in nodejs, and we have no clue how to translate some of the functions:

With the first function we would need to find a solution in nodejs for the **Cipher** class, which we haven't found yet, is there any "simmetric" or similar package that we can use in node?

```
public static String encryptBlowFish(String cleartext, String key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        String encBlowFish = "";
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = getGenerateKey(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(1, skeySpec);
        byte[] raw = cipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes("UTF8"));
        encBlowFish = new Base64Encoder().encode(raw);
        encBlowFish = URLEncoder.encode(encBlowFish, "UTF8");
        encBlowFish = specialChars(encBlowFish);
        return encBlowFish;
    }
```

For the second method it is pretty much the same, we need a solution in node to emulate this behaviour:

```
private static SecretKeySpec getGenerateKey(String key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = null;
        Provider sunJce = new SunJCE();
        Security.addProvider(sunJce);
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
        kgen.init(448);
        byte[] raw = key.getBytes();
        skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "Blowfish");
        return skeySpec;
    }
```

Since we've been surfing around and haven't found anything relevant appart from the package **"crypto"** for node, which looks nice but we don't know which methods to use to emulate the expected result.

If there is anything else I can do to help you understand our issue, please let me know.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you are migrating also consider upgrading to AES, even the author of Blowfish now uses AES,.

Comment: Interesting thoughts, sadly, we're not the ones who made this script and it's pointing into a third party which (we assume) need this to work as is, so changing the algorithm might cause malfunction. Now we're mostly struggling with the KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish") part, which we don't see any way to replicate it in Nodejs.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How do things like this ever get upgraded? From what I have seen the answer seems to be never.

Comment: I don't really know, it's the first time I have to deal with an approach like this and basically the crypto itself. At least we have been searching a lot regarding this matter but the internet seems to be empty (nodejs speaking).